# How to Remove Editors from Googlesheets Using Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble writing some JavaScript code in a googlesheet that will find all the current editors of the sheet (apart from the owner) and remove their edit writes. Currently I've been trying to use:

```js
//remove the current editors and only allow the origional owner to have access.
var SpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
SpreadSheet.removeEditor(SpreadSheet.getEditors())
```

This comes up with an "Invalid email:" with a string of editors emails. Is there a way to perhaps separate this email string then run the "removeEditor" code through a loop for the required number of editors that need to be removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to pass an array into a function that expects a single user. According to the GAS API, `getEditors()` returns an array of Users.  The `removeEditor()` function expects either an email address or a User object. Try looping through your array to remove the editors:

```
var SpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var editors = SpreadSheet.getEditors();
for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
     SpreadSheet.removeEditor(editors[i]);
    };
```

Comment: Thanks! that's the one I was looking for. I pretty much used it like in the variation below:

//remove the current editors and make them viewers and only allow the origional owner to have access.
  var DocEditors = SpreadSheet.getEditors()
   for (n in DocEditors) {
     if (DocEditors[n] != OrigionalEmail) { SpreadSheet.removeEditor(DocEditors[n]);}
        }